# UITableView inside UINavigationController

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

Im creating a UITableView inside my UINavigationController, and the problem is that the table is covering the header of it. This is my class:

.h:

```
@interface SecondViewController : UINavigationController

@end
```

And part of the .m:

```
- (id)init
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {

    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    UITableView *mmm = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0,320, 100) style:UITableViewStylePlain];

[self.view addsubview:mmm];


}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think this is what you want to do.

The documentation for `UINavigationController` advises against subclassing.  Instead, I think you want to create a `UITableViewController` and push that controller onto the navigation controller's stack (or if this is root view controller, then initialize a navigation controller with that `UITableViewController`.

```
MyTableViewController *tableController = [[MyTableViewController alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewStylePlain];
UINavigationController *navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:tableController];
//  now add the navController's view to the view hierarchy, however you intend to do that.
```

Answer (score 1):

The frame of your UITableView will start at origin point 0.0 , 0.0 witch is the origin point of your UINavigationController. Just change the

```
CGRectMake(0, 0,320, 100)
```

to

```
CGRectMake(0, 44,320, 100)
```

FYI it is not recommended to subclass a UINavigationCantroller.

Answer (score 1):

You are creating your frame for the UITableView with a top-left point of 0,0 on the screen.  This pulls your table up as high as can be allowed.  You can do one of two things to correct this:

1)  Build the View in IB and wire it to your controller.  IN IB you can tell the layout manager you have different controls displayed such as the status bar, navigation controller or tab bar.  Having these in place will allow you to precisely place the UITableView.

2)  Alter the Rect used to place your table view on the page.  You will need to add to the second argument to move the frame down.  You can play with how much you add until the table view is where you want it.  This number represents pixels and the higher the number, the lower on the screen the top-left corner of the control will be placed.

Good Luck!